# Python inverted hollow pyramid second row

Tags: python

I have a code:

```
r = int(input("Length of upper base of triangle = "))

print("Hollow Inverted Right Triangle Star Pattern") 

for i in range(1, r + 1):
    for j in range(1, 2*r):
        if (i == 1 and not j%2 == 0) or i == j or i + j == r*2:
            print('*', end = '')
        else:
            print(' ', end = '')
    print()
```

After the command I get:

```
* * * * * * * * * * *
 *                 * 
  *               *  
   *             *   
    *           *    
     *         *     
      *       *      
       *     *       
        *   *        
         * *         
          *
```

I wanted to modify the code to print star every second row, i. e.

```
* * * * * * * * * * *
  
  *               *

    *           *

      *       *

        *   *

          *
```

How to do this? It looks like the code needs a simple modification but I don't get it.

Comment: "It looks like the code needs a simple modification but I don't get it." Well, **what is different** between the current output and the desired output? (Hint: try printing them both out on real pieces of paper, and holding one over the other next to a light. Can you see what is missing or extra in one or the other? Does anything seem to be altered or shifted, or is there just something extra or missing?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to skip printing stars on every second line by printing a blank line and then continuing the loop.

You can use the modulus operator (`%`) to check if a line is even, and then skip that run of the loop.

```
r = int(input("Length of upper base of triangle = "))

print("Hollow Inverted Right Triangle Star Pattern") 

for i in range(1, r + 1):
    if i%2 == 0:
        print()
        continue
    for j in range(1, 2*r):
        if (i == 1 and not j%2 == 0) or i == j or i + j == r*2:
            print('*', end = '')
        else:
            print(' ', end = '')
    print()
```